# Sort item with Drag and Drop UWP MasterDetailsView

Tags: sorting, uwp, drag, items, drop

I'm implementing sorting items with Drag and Drop for a UWP MasterDetailsView, but it doesn't work. How could I achieve it?
Always thanks in advance!

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow! To get accurate answers is recommended to write what is the real problem, attach the portion of code interested and also explain what you've tried to solve the issues

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> Sort item with Drag and Drop UWP MasterDetailsView

I'm afraid you can't sort [`MasterDetailsView`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/communitytoolkit/controls/masterdetailsview) master items with drag and drop. Because `MasterDetailsView` does not support [`ReorderItems`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/uwp/api/windows.ui.xaml.controls.listviewbase.canreorderitems?view=winrt-19041) like `ListView`. If you do want this feature please feel free post your requirement in `Windows Community Toolkit` github. And you could also custom `MasterDetailsView` with [`SplitView`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/uwp/design/controls-and-patterns/split-view) control and insert ListView as master into SplitView's panel.

Comment: Thanks for the advice! I will try using SplitView as you recommended.